# How do I rewrite this rational expression?

Tags: rational-functions

How do I rewrite the rational expression:

$$\frac{x^3+5x^2+3x-10}{x+4}$$

But in the form of:

$$q(x) + \frac{r(x)}{b(x)}$$

Comment: Do you know how to do polynomial long division?

Answer (score 6):

Use [Polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division). The only way I know how to format that here would be something like:

$$\begin{split}
x^3 + 5x^2 + 3x - 10 &= (x+4)(x^2) + x^2 + 3x - 10 \\
&= (x+4)(x^2) + (x+4)(x) - x - 10 \\
&= (x+4)(x^2) + (x+4)(x) - (x+4)(1) - 6 \\
&= (x+4)(x^2 + x - 1) - 6
\end{split}$$

So:

$$\frac{x^3 + 5x^2 + 3x - 10}{x+4} = (x^2 + x - 1) + \frac{-6}{x+4}$$

Comment: I too would like to know how to format algebraic long division in mathjax..+1 for answer and effort!